# xsshunterexpress admin panel does'nt works

Tags: xss

I'm trying to login at xsshunterexpress with my browser but it's displaying `OOPS SOMETHING LOST`.

The DNS record suppose to be type A. In the docker compose file I have to change the HOSTNAME and the SSL_CONTACT_EMAIL. It is running on Kali Linux, the commands are :

```
docker-compose up -d postgresdb and docker-compose up xsshunterexpress.
```

It should be accessible via my subdomain just created on Hostinger. You can follow the process at these links.

blog.intigriti.com/2021/08/18/hacker-tools-xsshunter

github.com/mandatoryprogrammer/xsshunter-express